# How to get user fullname when i have only user code?

Tags: reactjs

```
 static getEmployeeByCode(code) {
        if (isMock) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve(Object.assign({}, employeeMock));
                });
            });
        }
        return axios.get(`${EmployeesUrl}/${code}`)
            .then(response => response.data);
    }
How i need to take fullname when i have only creator code?
```

I have a list page where news and suggestions posts, and there are comment what belonged for news and suggestions two another function and i have a creatorKod(comment creator) and have web service employeescode for get creator fullname by code. How can i do it with code on top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't actually get what you saying however how much I understand you want to return data from axios to another function for that you can use `callback` function to return specific data

Here's the complete code may help

```html
ApiEmployees.getEmployeeByCode=function(creatorKod, callback){
  axios.post('http://localhost:8080/comment',{
    code:data.user_code
  }).then(response =>{
    callback(response.data.message);
    callback(response.data.fullname
    console.log(response.data.message);
  }).catch(err =>{
    console.log(err);
  })
}
```

Comment: can u see again?